# How can I work out the width and height of a hexagon

Tags: c, math

Each side is 60 degrees. and the top and bottom sides are horizontal

I think `width = (cos(60) * sideLength * 2) + sideLength = sideLength * 2`

This seems a bit off

Comment: Since you only want formula, you may ask on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: They don't allow any questions below nuclear physics level

Comment: That's correct for the width (see the animated construction on the wikipedia page for intuition)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

width should be `2*sideLength` (`sideLength = cos(60) * sideLength * 2`)

height will be `sin(60) * sideLength * 2 = sqrt(3)*sideLength`

Comment: Can you possibly update the formatting on this answer? I'm confused about that equal sine in front of cos(60) and also, I dont see how sin(6) * 5 * 2 = sqrt(3) * 5. It looks like you're trying to say there are two ways to do both, but both give different results.

Comment: @netpoetica, `cos(60) = 1/2`, `sin(60) = sqrt(3)/2`. Let me know if that doesn't clear it up, and I'll be a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rubbish at maths so Wolfram Alpha is my go to site for *any* formula questions:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonal+of+hexagon

and it agrees with @jswolf19: `sqrt(3) * sideLength`

Comment: +1 for Wolfram Alpha = math.stackexchange.com evolved into AI.

Comment: Actually if you check your link you'll see its 2 * sideLength ;)

Comment: @Goz: no, it offers three formula for the three possible diagonals from each vertex: `s | sqrt(3)s | 2s` - from the OPs question: height would be `sqrt(3)s` and width `2s`

Comment: Sorry ... I'm being a muppet :D

Answer (score -2):

It is simple trigonometry.  Divide the polygon into triangles that you can solve.

For example, imagine a vertical line from the top-left to bottom left corner, then bisect this with a perpendicular line from the middle-left corner.  You now have two identical triangles with two known angles (90deg and 30 deg, and a known hypotenuse).  The *opposite* side of this triangle is half the height and is equal to sin(theta) * hypotenuse.

So the height is 2 * sin(60) * sideLength.

Similarly the width is the sideLength + 2 * length of adjacent side  = sidelength + cos(60) * sideLength * 2.

Comment: Umm, no... `2 * sin(30)` = 1, so you're saying the height is the same as one sideLength!

Comment: @GrahamS: Good point ;)  I read *"Each side is 60 degrees."* in the original and took that to mean the size of the internal angle, without second guessing it, but of course the size of the internal angle is 120 degrees.  Duly modified, but @jswolf19 already gave that in any case.